# XSLT - How to select XML Attribute by Attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-attribute

this is the structure of my source xml:

```
<root>
<DataSet Value="A">
<Data Value1="1" Value2="anythingA1" />
<Data Value1="2" Value2="anythingA2" />
<Data Value1="3" Value2="anythingA3" />
<Data Value1="4" Value2="anythingA4" />
<Data Value1="5" Value2="anythingA5" />
</DataSet>
</root>
```

from which I like to create some variables e.g. from all with Value1="2" and all with Value1="5" should result myVar1 with anythingA2 and myVar2 with anythingA5

My approch looks like this

```
<xsl:variable name="myVarA" select="/DataSet/Data/[@Value1='2']/@Value2" />
```

but of course is not working since Value2 is no child of Value1.

thanks for any hints in advance!

Answer (score 49):

Just remove the slash after `Data` and prepend the root:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVarA" select="/root/DataSet/Data[@Value1='2']/@Value2"/>
```

Comment: @Andrew Hare: Corrected. Thanks to Quassnoi for elaborating, I lost connection immediately after posting the first revision.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your xpath - first you need to remove the child selector from after `Data` like phihag mentioned.  Also you forgot to include `root` in your xpath.  Here is what you want to do:

```
select="/root/DataSet/Data[@Value1='2']/@Value2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
xsl:variable name="myVarA" select="//DataSet/Data[@Value1='2']/@Value2" />
```

The '//' will search for DataSet at any depth

Answer (score 1):

Note: using // at the beginning of the xpath is a bit CPU intensitve -- it will search every node for a match.  Using a more specific path, such as /root/DataSet will create a faster query.

Comment: As this does not answer the question, it should be a comment on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by creating a variable that points to the nodes that have the proper value in Value1 then referring to t

```
<xsl:variable name="myVarANode" select="root//DataSet/Data[@Value1='2']" />
<xsl:value-of select="$myVarANode/@Value2"/>
```

Everyone else's answers are right too - more right in fact since I didn't notice the extra slash in your XPATH that would mess things up.  Still, this will also work , and might work for different things, so keep this method in your toolbox.

Comment: Is the 1, 2, 3 stuff hypothetical?  I've got <cd><album>Album Name</album><artist>Artist A</artist><artist>Artist B></artist></cd>, and I am trying to select all sibling artists and tie them to an intermediary table connected to the album, without having duplicate artists from my enormous database.  Any ideas?