# xslt : how to select an XML element according to the value of a sibling element

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML :

```
<root>
<parameters>
<parameter>
    <key>sEmail</key>
    <value>cauchyjp@gmail.com</value>
    <type>string</type>
    <length>255</length>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <key>sFirstName</key>
    <value>Bill</value>
    <type>string</type>
    <length>40</length>
</parameter>
</parameters>
<root>
```

I want to retrieve the value of the key sEmail and add it as an attribute to the root element using XML to XML xslt.

Here is the result expected :

```
<root email="cauchyjp@gmail.com">
<parameters>
    <parameter>
        <key>sEmail</key>
        <value>cauchyjp@gmail.com</value>
        <type>string</type>
        <length>255</length>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <key>sFirstName</key>
        <value>Bill</value>
        <type>string</type>
        <length>40</length>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
<root>
```

Something similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541370/xslt-how-to-select-xml-attribute-by-attribute) but with value of element instead of attributes.

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if a subelement's value is 'sEmail':

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="parameters">
    <parameters>
      <xsl:attribute name="email">
        <xsl:value-of select="parameter[key='sEmail']/value"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </parameters>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: perfect, can accept your answer in 2min. Was trying to do the same but trhough a variable, don't know why it didn't worked

Comment: @Lucas you are welcome to ask why your approach didn't work (in a new question). This might help understanding XSLT, it usually does for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Can be done in a cleaner way using [AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root email="{*/*[key = 'sEmail']/value}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <parameters>
        <parameter>
            <key>sEmail</key>
            <value>cauchyjp@gmail.com</value>
            <type>string</type>
            <length>255</length>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <key>sFirstName</key>
            <value>Bill</value>
            <type>string</type>
            <length>40</length>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root email="cauchyjp@gmail.com">
   <parameters>
      <parameter>
         <key>sEmail</key>
         <value>cauchyjp@gmail.com</value>
         <type>string</type>
         <length>255</length>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
         <key>sFirstName</key>
         <value>Bill</value>
         <type>string</type>
         <length>40</length>
      </parameter>
   </parameters>
</root>
```